# Is it okay to have too many answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Questions such as [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/236/in-the-100-blue-eyes-problem-why-is-the-oracle-necessary) have way too many answers. Isn't that a problem? One could justify that each answer explains thing a bit differently, but I can't imagine the answer to a simple question being explained in *nineteen* different ways. Somebody even put an answer 3 days ago, and it doesn't help explain the answer as well as the initial ones. As it is, getting more than 10-15 upvotes on an answer today is more or less impossible.

Isn't there any way to prevent this? Maybe a moderator could deny the right to answer on that question to people with less rep (say, below 1000). There are so many answers that relying on users' downvotes entirely is not going to solve anything.

Comment: Users with some amount of rep (3500 on betas, 15k on graduated) can [protect questions](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), which prevents answers from users with less than 10 rep on the site (note that the 100 rep association bonus doesn't count towards that).

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I know that. (And it barely helps solve the problem)

Comment: I don't see why it is necessarily a problem for a question to have a ton of answers.

Comment: A question with a high number of answers isn't inherently a bad one, but it _could_ indicate something is off. It also could simply indicate that everyone has something to say about it. In other words, evaluate each on a case-by-case basis, possibly using answer count to inform the scrutiny with which you consider your judgment.

Comment: @Emrakul I'm not saying the question is a bad one. I'm just saying that the question is so popular that it is natural for a person to attempt writing his own answer, without even bothering to read all the other answers. This leads to a lot of duplicacy but not directly.

Comment: Meaning that I cannot declare Answer A is a duplicate of Answer B, hence Answer B should be removed. However, I could declare that Answers A to G more or less say the same thing in different words. Answer A, however, is really clear, hence Answers B to G should be deleted as they waste the future readers's time.

Comment: My 2¢:  I had never really understood the solution to this problem, and I remember encountering this question and reading through the answers.  It wasn't until I had read a half-dozen of them that the solution really began to make sense intuitively.  Particularly with a question like this, that doesn't intuitively make sense at the beginning, it can be helpful to hear many different takes, even if they are very similar; each person describes things a little differently.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Is it that you read many answers until you stumbled upon an answer that made more sense, or is it that every answer you read was helpful in some way?

Comment: @ghosts It was some of both. Some explanations definitely made more sense to me than others, but each one contributed to my understanding nonetheless.